# How to use replace when making one variable = two others instead of just one

Tags: vb.net, string

Okay this one might be a little tougher.  I'm using VB that looks like this:

```
string = Replace(string.ToLower, chr(63), "A")
```

But I also want chr(63) = "B" as well, like this:

```
string = Replace(string.ToLower, chr(63), "B")
```

My problem is that when chr(63) is at the end of a string I need it to be B, and when it's not the end I need it to be A.  I suppose that I can use an if/then/else statement.  Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
XXXXXchr(63)XXXXX = A
```

but

```
XXXXXXXXXXchr(63) = B
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 but it was written in VB

Answer (score 1):

```
pseudo:
if (string[string.Length] == chr(63))
{
   string[string.Length] = B
}
string = Replace(string.ToLower, chr(63), "A")
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but not quite what I need.  Rather than length (which I don't know)  I need it to be B ONLY if it's at the end of the string.  Know what I mean?  Example:
chr(63) = ?  So if the word ends in a ?  I need it to be B and anything else I need to be A.  Hope this makes sense!  Thanks!

Comment: You're not describing the problem well. The string object should know the length, so the above code should work, provided that string is 1-based, but it is pseudo-code so that is ok. Otherwise, if there is no way for your code to tell whether it has found the ? at the end or not, there's no way to do the code either.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = Replace(string.ToLower, chr(63), "A", 1, Len(string) - 1)
If Right(string, 1) = chr(63) then
   Mid$(string, Len(string), 1) = 'B'
End if
```

**Update**: in response to comment:

- [VB String Functions](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions)
- [VB String Array Functions - Split, Join, Filter](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter) (very useful)

Comment: You'll have to forgive my lack of knowledge of VB functions, I'm just learning.  Does Len(string) also stand for length of the string?  and how does the -1 and 1 come into play.  I'm very new to this.  Thanks!

Comment: yes. Len(string) gives a string's length. Replace has these parameters: Replace$(expression, find, replacewith[, start[, count[, compare]]])  (square brackets denote optional parameters)

Comment: Okay so I tried using this method and I ran into a problem.  I have 2 errors coming up, both for "Right".  It has them underlined and I don't have enough knowledge of what it does to figure out why.  Everything else seems to check out.  Any clues why it's having this issue?

Comment: Lol okay I understand what right/left mean now thanks to you guys and I get why.  However, my VB doesn't seem to recognize Right and even though I changed the 2nd one to mid, the first one is still Right and doesn't allow it to work.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Visual Basic since version 6, but it should be something like this:

```
If Robert.EndsWith(chr(63)) Then
    Robert = Left(Robert, Robert.Length - 1) + "B"
End If
```

Then do the usual replacement with A.

Comment: Could part of my problem be because I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it

```
    Dim s As String 
    Dim char63 As String = Convert.ToChar(63).ToString
    If s.EndsWith(char63) Then
        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) & "B"
    End If
    s = s.Replace(char63, "A")
```